# Localize Google Sign in button in Flutter web

Tags: flutter-web, firebaseui, flutter-localizations

I'm following [the official Firebase UI guide](https://firebase.flutter.dev/docs/ui/auth/localization) to localize Firebase UI Google Sign in button in a different language, but I'm already using [Intl package](https://pub.dev/packages/intl) as for [the official Flutter guide](https://docs.flutter.dev/development/accessibility-and-localization/internationalization#an-alternative-class-for-the-apps-localized-resources), so I don't understand what is the *custom delegate* which should extend `LocalizationsDelegate<FlutterFireUILocalizations>` nor which are the labels I have to change in the different *specific widgets*.

As for the Flutter guide, I have an `AppLocalizations` class which is generated, I cannot change it. This is causing my confusion.

Can anybody point me to the right direction?